# Using @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations is updating one entity table but not the many table

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm, h2

I have a Spring restful API that is using a H2 database and JPA to populate some tables. I am trying to set up one entity with a field `@OneToMany`and the other entity object is the `@ManyToOne`. When I make a  POST request in Postman I `sout` my `Quiz quiz` that is the request body and the fields are as expected. Yet when I log in to the database on localhost, only the `quiz_table` is updated with the correct properties.

I get this output in the console when I do a POST request

```
Hibernate: insert into quiz_table (answer, text, title, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

My JSON request body is

```
{
    "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
    "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
    "options": ["2002", "2019"],
    "answer": 1
}
```

The server response is

```
{
    "id": 67,
    "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
    "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
    "options": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "quiz": null,
            "option": "2002"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "quiz": null,
            "option": "2019"
        }
    ]
}
```

As far as I can tell the values for `"options"` are being passed to the `List<Option>`
Here is my controller with the mapping for this endpoint

```
 @PostMapping(path = "api/quizzes", produces = "application/json")
    public Quiz addQuiz(@Valid @RequestBody Quiz quiz) {
        quizRepository.save(quiz);
        return quiz;
    }
```

The `Quiz` class

```
@Component
@Entity(name = "quiz_table")
public class Quiz {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Title must not be blank")
    private String title;

    @NotBlank(message = "Text must not be blank")
    private String text;

    @Size(min = 2)
//    @NotNull
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quiz")
    private List<Option> options;

    @JsonIgnore
    private int answer;

    public Quiz() {}

    public Quiz(String title, String text, List<Option> options, int answer) {
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
        this.options = options;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
```

The `Option` class

```
@Component
@Entity(name = "options_table")
public class Option {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Quiz quiz;

    private String option;

    // for Jackson deserielization
    public Option() {
    }

    /*public Option(Quiz quiz, String option) {
        this.quiz = quiz;
        this.option = option;

    }*/

    public Option(String option) {
        this.option = option;
    }
    // getters/setters
```

[image]

Edit: Unusual JSON response after implementing advice

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
    "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
    "options": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "quiz": {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "quiz": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                            "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                            "options": [
                                {
                                    "id": 2,
                                    "quiz": {
                                        "id": 1,
                                        "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                                        "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                                        "options": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 2,
                                                "quiz": {
                                                    "id": 1,
                                                    "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                                                    "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                                                    "options": [
                                                        {
                                                            "id": 2,
                                                            "quiz": {
                                                                "id": 1,
                                                                "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                                                                "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                                                                "options": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "id": 2,
                                                                        "quiz": {
                                                                            "id": 1,
                                                                            "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                                                                            "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                                                                            "options": [
                                                                                {
                                                                                    "id": 2,
                                                                                    "quiz": {
                                                                                        "id": 1,
                                                                                        "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                                                                                        "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                                                                                        "options": [
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                "id": 2,
                                                                                                "quiz": {
                                                                                                    "id": 1,
                                                                                                    "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                                                                                                    "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                                                                                                    "options": [
                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                            "id": 2,
                                                                                                            "quiz": {
                                                                                                                "id": 1,
                                                                                                                "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                                                                                                                "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                                                                                                                "options": [
                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                        "id": 2,
                                                                                                                        "quiz": {
                                                                                                                            "id": 1,
                                                                                                                            "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                                                                                                                            "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                                                                                                                            "options": [
                                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                                    "id": 2,
                                                                                                                                    "quiz": {
                                                                                                                                        "id": 1,
                                                                                                                                        "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                                                                                                                                        "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                                                                                                                                        "options": [
                                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                                "id": 2,
                                                                                                                                                "quiz": {
                                                                                                                                                    "id": 1,
                                                                                                                                                    "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                                                                                                                                                    "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win a trophy?",
                                                                                                                                                    "options": [
                                                                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                                                                            "id": 2,
                                                                                                                                                            "quiz": {
                                                                                                                                                                "id": 1,
                                                                                                                                                                "title": "Tottenham Quiz",
                                                                                                                                                                "text": "When did Tottenham Hotspur last win 
// ... continues for 4000 lines!
```

Comment: Did you try adding cascading options? I think that's the reason you can't save the child entities.

Comment: I completely overlooked this.  I guess there's no default setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- With JPA/Hibernate you need to explicitly manage bi-directional relationship

```
    @PostMapping(path = "api/quizzes", produces = "application/json")
   public Quiz addQuiz(@Valid @RequestBody Quiz quiz) {
       quiz.getOptions().forEach(option -> option.setQuiz(quiz));
       quizRepository.save(quiz);
       return quiz;
   }
```

- And also, you have to tell hibernate, when it manages `Quiz`, cascade `Option` too

```
    @Size(min = 2)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quiz", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Option> options;
```

Comment: It has worked thank you. Complete oversight on my part, the CascadeType was taught but I didn't understand it had to be explicitly declared.
I am though getting a unusual JSON response, it seems to be a recursively adding the returning the quizzes in the response. I will post a snippet into the main post.

Comment: That is not a hibernate issue. That is jackson issue. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623483/i-am-using-manytoone-onetomany-and-have-endless-loop-when-getting-data/62623772#62623772

Comment: Let me know if you get stuck